# Remove Google Jquery in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to remove jQuery from Google CDN on my WordPress site. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YKTE.jpg)

I want to remove that, because I already have jquery script on my website. And also the jQuery from Google takes 1.1s too load. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPfSg.jpg)

I tried to add this script on the function.php

```
    function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery-js');
        wp_register_script('jquery-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js', false);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

But it's not working. So do you guys know how to remove the jQuery script from Google in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried deregister without .js ?
like this:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```